# How to analyze .class files using soot?

Tags: java, code-analysis, static-analysis, call-graph, soot

I'm trying to build a call-graph(CG) for spotbugs-4.0.2 with soot. The code is shown as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String analyzed_classes_dir = "C:\\Users\\lyu\\lll\\src\\test\\java\\com\\demo\\dir3\\spotbugs"; //contains all structured class files
    String mainclass = "edu.umd.cs.findbugs.LaunchAppropriateUI";

    //set classpath
    String javapath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String jredir = System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\lib\\rt.jar";
    String libs = "C:\\Users\\liuyu\\lll\\src\\test\\java\\com\\demo\\libs\\spotbugs-4.0.2\\";
    String path = javapath + File.pathSeparator + jredir + File.pathSeparator + libs;

    Scene.v().setSootClassPath(path);

    //add an intra-procedural analysis phase to Soot
    TestCallGraphSootJar_3 analysis = new TestCallGraphSootJar_3();
    PackManager.v().getPack("wjtp").add(new Transform("wjtp.TestSootCallGraph", analysis));

    excludeJDKLibrary();

    Options.v().set_process_dir(Arrays.asList(analyzed_classes_dir));
    Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
    Options.v().set_no_bodies_for_excluded(true);
    Options.v().set_allow_phantom_refs(true);

    Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
    SootClass appclass = Scene.v().getSootClass(mainclass);
    Scene.v().setMainClass(appclass); // exception here.

    enableSparkCallGraph();

    PackManager.v().runPacks();
}
```

Then the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Main-class has no main method!
at soot.Scene.setMainClass(Scene.java:187)
at com.ouc.TestCallGraphSootJar_3.main(TestCallGraphSootJar_3.java:65)
```

The statement "Scene.v().setMainClass(appclass);" throws the above exception.
I debugged it and found that the `methodlst` in the `appclass` is null. And `appclass` is phantom.
As shown in the picture.
[fig. the debug information of appclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsF2k.png)

The `mainclass` does exist in the specified path, and it does contain the main method.

I've submitted an issue in GitHub (https://github.com/Sable/soot/issues/1346#issuecomment-627551137) but didn't solve it. And the [options manual](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/public/origin/develop/soot/soot-develop/options/soot_options.htm) also didn't help with this problem.

Btw, could I only analyze the call relationships in a given class? For example, I only want to get the call information inside the class C1.

```
Class C1{
  main(){
    m1(parm);
  }

  m1(args){
    m2(xxx);
  }

  m2(args){
    m3(xxx);
  }

  m3(args){
    ...  
  }
}
```

Then I only want to get the follow call relationship:

```
main——>m1()——>m2()——m3()
```

If main or m1 or m2 or m3 calls a method in another class C2, I will ignore it, only focus on the methods in C1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the asker, and I've solved it. If you are interested in this question, you can read it in this issue [post](https://github.com/Sable/soot/issues/1346).